# Dynamically include associations for objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.4

I am currently developing a small Rails 5 application where I need to pass on an ActiveRecord object to an external service based on certain events. In my model I have defined the following:

```
# /models/user.rb
after_create :notify_external_service_of_user_creation

def notify_external_service_of_user_creation
  EventHandler.new(
    event_kind: :create_user,
    content: self
  )
end
```

The `EventHandler` is then converting this object to JSON and is sending it through an HTTP request to the external service. By calling `.to_json` on the object this renders a JSON output which would look something like this:

```
{
  "id":1234,
  "email":"test@testemail.dk",
  "first_name":"Thomas",
  "last_name":"Anderson",
  "association_id":12,
  "another_association_id":356
}
```

Now, I need a way to include all first level associations directly into this, instead of just showing the foreign_key. So the construct I am looking for would be something like this:

```
{
  "id":1234,
  "email":"test@testemail.dk",
  "first_name":"Thomas",
  "last_name":"Anderson",
  "association_id":{
    "attr1":"some_data",
    "attr2":"another_value"
  },
  "another_association_id":{
    "attr1":"some_data",
    "attr2":"another_value"
  },
}
```

My first idea was to reflect upon the Model like so: `object.class.name.constantize.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name)`, where `object` is an instance of a user in this case, and use this list to loop over the associations and include them in the output. This seems rather tedious though, so I was wondering if there would be a better way of achieving this using Ruby 2.4 and Rails 5.

Comment: What do you use for JSON serialization? https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers supports associations.

Comment: @MikDiet I am calling `.to_json` on the obejct, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use an external serializer, you can override `as_json` for each model. `as_json` gets called by `to_json`.

```
module JsonWithAssociations
  def as_json
    json_hash = super

    self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name).each do |assoc_name|
      assoc_hash = if send(assoc_name).respond_to?(:first)
                     send(assoc_name).try(:map, &:as_json) || [] 
                   else
                     send(assoc_name).as_json 
                   end

      json_hash.merge!(assoc_name.to_s => assoc_hash)
    end 

    json_hash
  end
end
```

You'll need to `prepend` this particular module so that it overrides the default `as_json` method.

```
User.prepend(JsonWithAssociations)
```

or

```
class User
  prepend JsonWithAssociations
end
```